Правильность оформления вставной конструкции у Тургенева
Из романа Тургенева "Новь":
Благодарный взгляд, брошенный ему Марианной(,) — она стояла у окна гостиной(,) — заставил его призадуматься.
Как по Розенталю объяснить постановку запятых при обособлении вводной конструкции? У Розенталя  говорится о структуре первой или второй части, но не всегда понятно, что имеется в виду.
Вызывает сомнение вторая запятая. Предложение включают в учебные пособия, поэтому желательно определиться с запятыми.
Розенталь, пункт 4
2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения;
3) перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции: Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну (Кав.) — вставному предложению предшествует деепричастие, и запятая ставится, после всей этой конструкции;
Прихвастнуть любил — этот грех за ним водился, — может, и тут что приплёл для красного словца (Фурм.) — вторая часть начинается вводным словом, которое требует выделения запятыми;

Она стояла у окна гостиной - это разве вводная конструкция?

@Серж А почему нет?

А какое значение оно имеет?

@Серж Какое значение? Как обычно, добавочная информация. Но даже не в этом дело. Главное, что вставка не вписывается в предложение ни по семантике, ни по грамматике:  мешает порядок слов и личное местоимение. Это характерный признак вставных конструкций.

Так я и не спорю по поводу вставных конструкций. Это и так очевидно. Вы пишете о вводной конструкции. Но вводное конструкция не имеет значения добавочной информации.

Шарон, в этом предложении две запятые. В том справочнике, о котором я вам говорил в прошлый раз, написано: запятая обусловлена предшествующий частью основного предложения.

@Серж, ну почему же  две запятые, откуда? Я считаю, что одна.
Благодарный взгляд, брошенный ему Марианной, — она стояла у окна гостиной — заставил его призадуматься. // Уберем обособленный оборот, и вообще нет запятых: Благодарный взгляд — она стояла у окна гостиной — заставил его призадуматься. // В структуре первой части есть обособленный оборот, который  определяет постановку первой запятой. И это все, поэтому второй запятой нет.

Sharon, согласен. Но в справочнике так написано.

Я думаю, что оформление вставки должно быть таким, без второй запятой:
Благодарный взгляд, брошенный ему Марианной, — она стояла у окна гостиной — заставил его призадуматься.
Пояснение

Трудно сказать, какие правила были у Грота в XIX веке — возможно, эта тема не излагалась подробно. Поэтому встречаются варианты с симметричной постановкой знаков. Править их, разумеется, не будут.

Но попробуем решить задачу по Розенталю, так как это более современный и дифференцированный подход. Что такое структура предложения в данной теме. Это, конечно, вопрос.

В грамматике существует понятие параллельных структур (у Прияткиной, например). Имеется в виду не параллельные конструкции (определительное придаточное и причастный оборот), а именно структуры в конкретном предложении. Точное определение не приводится, но попробуем использовать термин для решения конкретной задачи с постановкой запятых.

К примеру, параллельными можно считать пояснительные и уточняющие члены, а также определительные обороты всякого рода, в том числе придаточное определительное и сравнительный оборот. Такие структуры не входят в общую линейную структуру предложения, а частным образом поясняют и определяют отдельные слова.
У Розенталя: Смеялся он мало — настолько у него хватало чувства такта, — но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах. Основная конструкция: Смеялся он мало, но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах. Здесь запятая относится к структуре второй части.
Сравнить: Смеялся он мало, особенно в гостях, — настолько у него хватало чувства такта, — но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах. Здесь уже уточнение как параллельная конструкция, и оно относится к структуре первой части. Поэтому ставятся обе запятые.

Решение задачи

Благодарный взгляд, брошенный ему Марианной, — она стояла у окна гостиной — заставил его призадуматься. Ставится только первая запятая.
Основная структура предложения: Благодарный взгляд Марианны  заставил его призадуматься. Причастный оборот относится только к первой части предложения, а без него здесь структура простого предложения, в котором нет знаков. Поэтому второй запятой нет.

Мы разобрали достаточно простую конструкции, но встречаются и спорные варианты, особенно среди предложений с вводными словами. Такие слова по смыслу чаще относятся ко всему предложению, но по структуре входят в его первую или вторую часть. Другими словами, относятся к  линейной структуре.

Пример с форума, где участники обсуждают запятую: Чего я, кстати, — при всей моей солидарности с коллегами — не делаю.
Основная конструкция: Чего, кстати, я  не делаю.  Вводное сочетание по смыслу отнесено ко всему предложению, но по структуре — к первой части. Поэтому ставится первая запятая.
Сравнить: Чего я — при всей моей солидарности с коллегами, — кстати, не делаю.
